# Spring - Where to find the distribution jar files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I will be starting to learn spring so I tried to download the latest sping version but I have encountered a problem and Im stuck. I can't find the distribution jar files. All I can see are java source files.

Here are the steps I did :

1. I went to this link [projects](http://spring.io/projects)
2. I clicked the [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) link.
3. I checked the page and found nothing until I noticed the [Cat Image](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework)
4. Download the zip and extracted it.
5. I checked the folder `spring-core` and found `src` folder. I tried to find any `dist` folder but found nothing except java files.

I did not bother to open all folders because I think it would be a waste of time.
Please help me. Im just starting to learn and now a bit frustrated.

Comment: Consider using Maven.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/ Honestly, there's no reason not to use a build system / dependency manager with Java. Your IDE will also fully integrate with Maven. If you really, really insist on downloading jars manually, you can get them from [Maven central](http://search.maven.org)

Comment: SotiriosDelimanolis and BrianRoach I will consider your suggestions. Thanks you very much. Its just Im still confused on what to do.

Comment: Just a couple of comments:

Comment: Just a couple of comments: 1) the 'cat image' is the link to GitHub where the source code resides 2) from the source you can build the distribution jars - on the GitHub page it mentioned part way down to run ./gradlew build - which will build Spring from the source.  There is also a link on that GitHub page titled 'Downloading the artifacts' which takes you to a page that helps you with downloading from Maven, as @SotiriosDelimanolis suggested.   If you are new to Spring, as it sounds, using Maven is probably quicker.

Comment: @mikemil Im actually virgin to Spring and MVC altogether. LOL

Comment: So building Spring from the source may be a bit too big of a bite to start with.  If you can use maven to point to your test Spring code that would be a bit easier.   Possibly a better option for you would be to read thru this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469542/downloading-spring-jars-without-using-maven because there is a link to downloading the jars - then all you need to do is pointto them whereever you save them on your box.

Comment: Hey.. before you go for maven, look at Gradle, it is a mix of maven and ant. You can use Maven repo and also use Ant style script. Great tool, no need to manually add .jars.

Answer (score 1):

1) consider all comments already given on your question, gradle and maven are very helpfull, and help you with nested dependecies

2) http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/